# Swift 2.1: Property cannot be marked dynamic?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, swift2, key-value-observing

How do I fix this compilation error?

```
dynamic var users = [User]()
```

> Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

I need `dynamic` so that certain view controllers can observe (via KVO) `users` and update their views when `users` changes.

Comment: Pretty clear error message. Which word don't you understand?

Comment: I understand it. I don't know how to fix it. See updates.

Comment: Is user subclass of NSObject?

Comment: @vikingosegundo no, it wasn't. I think making it a subclass of `NSObject` worked! Thanks! :-) If I remember correctly, in an earlier version of Swift, it worked without being a subclass of `NSObject`, i.e., only the observer had to be a subclass of `NSObject`. I like it better that way because I don't understand why `User` needs to be a subclass of `NSObject`.

Comment: I think the observed object always needed to be of subclass NSObject. as to is also stated in this article from february. http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/02/11/swift-kvo-alternatives.html

Answer (score 4):

Just as the error mentions

error, not `@objc : NSObject`:

```
class A{

}

func something(){
    dynamic var a = [A]()
}
```

should be changed to:

```
@objc class A:NSObject{

}

func something(){
    dynamic var a = [A]() //works, all good
}
```

Comment: Using `@objc` when inheriting from `NSObject` is obsolete. It's implicit for any inheritance from `NSObject`